# How to get rid off warning in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am getting the below react warning:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the `componentWillUnmount` method.

What I am trying to do?

I display a content `div` box for each element on the page. If the element is not present on the page, then the content `div` box for that element is not shown.

In doing so, for one particular element, I click it before showing the content box, and check whether or not some other element is present *after* the click (since the node is present in the dom only after clicking).

In doing so, I get the above warning..otherwise, it works fine. I want to get rid of that warning.

Below is the code:

```
on_render = async () => {
   await global.ChildComponent.toggle(true);
   const li_elements = document.getElementByClassName('.drawer ul')[0];
   const no_li_elements = li_elements && li_elements.children.length === 0;

   if (no_li_elements) {
       on_skip();//here i execute skip
   }
   //if li elements present then displays the content div box
}
```

I think this is because I'm using `async` here.
Could someone help me fix this.

Comment: can you post the whole component (js file)

Comment: in general the warning can be resolved by calling `setState` in `componentDidMount` instead of calling `setState` in the `render` method.